# Some methods of Notification in android marshmallow are not working

Tags: android, notifications

I am trying to use Notification in my app. My device is Huawei Honor 5C (Marshmallow). I am simply trying to implement the methods that are used in Notification.My Issue is:

1. If i want to add action to the notification, the action (button)
   won't show up unless i drag the notification to expand it.
2. If i want to show big text (more than one line)  using the `setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(text));`  still it won't show unless i drag to expand it.
3. Neither the Color is set Nor the icon for the action (button) is shown.

Actually I don't think 100% that it is Huawei issue because some system notifications show action buttons when notified as shown below

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wt6So.png)

Comment: Try testing on something else (emulator or another device). For those things that are consistently not working, post a separate question with a [mcve], which would include the code that is creating the `Notification` and links to screenshots showing the results. If the emulator works, and the Honor 5C does not, then this is a problem with Huawei compatibility, and it is likely that there is nothing that you can do about it.

Comment: Yes the code works well on emulator very well. Ok. Thank You

Comment: But other system notification shows action buttons when notified.